# ¿Qué debe tener un sistema de perfil de usuarios ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2015, webforms

Buen día,
Siguiendo unos tutoriales de Mudassar Ahmed Khan, realicé unos webforms para:

- Crear usuario
- Link de activacion de usuario mediante correo
- Login de Usuario
- Recuperación de Contraseña
- Cambio de Contraseña

La pregunta es, ¿qué más recomiendan que pueda hacer el usuario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depende mucho de que tipo de sistema sea el que estés desarrollando (abierto al público con autoregistro, o administrado) pero entre lo que más se usa:

- Segundo paso de verificación, puede ser opcional o mandatario.
- Login mediante terceros(Gmail,Facebook, Twitter, etc.).
- Darse de baja.
- Historial de conexiones(tipo dispositivo, OS, ip, fecha y hora).
- Notificaciones de conexiones en equipos nuevos.
- Vencimiento programado de contraseña( escoger si nunca vence, si vence en un tiempo x).
- Contraseña de un solo uso (envió de una contraseña temporal descartable, aun medio verificado, teléfono o email), para ingresar de una única vez al sistema si reestablecer la contraseña, esto es útil en caso de olvido temporal, o no tener acceso al segundo paso de verificación, ejemplo el app de google para autenticacion.

Answer (score 1):

- Autenticación externa a través de 3ros ya sea Google o Facebook
- Cancelar su cuenta